# Isn't "grouped together" redundant? If not, how does it change the meaning from just "together"?

Tags: differences, phrase-usage, redundancy

Is the word 'together' redundant in this sentence?

> Keys are grouped together in a keychain.

I mean, how is that any different from

> Keys are grouped in a keychain.

I find the first sentence commonly used for this type of scenario.

Can you please explain the difference?

Comment: Have you looked up group (verb) in a dictionary? [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/group) says "to assign to a group" as well as "to combine in a group". And how do you envisage the keys being combined? Do you mean they are all on one key chain, are there multiple key chains, or are the keys divided into different groups in one set of keys?

Comment: I don't want to make it complex.  I just want to understand whether the second sentence is sufficient or is the word 'together' makes any difference in the first sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The word *grouped* can mean organised into groups, for example "the twenty students were grouped into five fours". Using *grouped together* means that when they are grouped they are put together, as in "Peter and John were grouped together".

In your example, using *together* states that if anything else is on the keychain it is not among the keys. It also emphasises that there is only one group of keys.

Comment: The word grouped itself means put together right?

Comment: Just to add: *grouped* does not force the meaning of *together*. Items can be grouped into separate areas. Men and women were grouped into two rooms - we understand that men went here and women there. And an extra word for emphasis or clarity don't hurt none.